# rxjs poll for data on timer and reset timerwhen manually refreshed

Tags: rxjs

I am using the following libraries in the relevant application: Angular 4.x, ngrx 4.x, rxjs 5.4.x

I have an api that I need to poll every 5 minutes. The user is also able to manually refresh the data. That data is stored in an ngrx store. I am using ngrx effects so the data is retrieved by dispatching an action of type 'FETCH'.

I want to setup a rxjs stream where it will dispatch the 'FETCH' action to the ngrx store. It will be a sliding 5 minute timer that resets when the user manually updates the store. The stream should initially emit a value when subscribed.

I'm not sure how I can reset the timer. In plain javascript I would do something like the following:

```js
console.clear();
let timer;
let counter = 0;

function fetch() {
  console.log('fetch', counter++);
  poll();
}

function poll() {
  if (timer != null) {
    window.clearTimeout(timer);
  }
  timer = window.setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('poll');
    fetch();
  }, 5000);
}

function manualGet() {
  console.log('manual');
  fetch();
}

fetch();
```

```html
<button onClick="manualGet()">Get Data</button>
```

**Question:** How do I emit on an interval that is reset when another stream emits like the example again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want two components to your stream – a timer and some user input. So let's start with the user input. I'll assume some button which can be clicked:

```
const userInput$ = Observable.fromEvent(button, 'click');
```

Now we want to start a timer which resets everytime `userInput$` emits. We can do that using

```
userInput$.switchMap(() => Observable.timer(0, 5000));
```

However, we also want this stream to start without the user having to first click the button. But that's also not a problem:

```
userInput$.startWith(null);
```

Now we put it all together:

```
Observable.fromEvent(button, 'click')
    .startWith(null)
    .switchMap(() => Observable.timer(0, 5000))
    .subscribe(() => dispatchFetch());
```

*Note* that I am following your examples of using a 5 second timer, not a 5 minute timer (which you mentioned in the question.)

Answer (score 0):

After writing it out in vanilla JS I realized that the source of the timer should be the data. I was struggling to figure out what the source would be. Clearly it couldn't be the timer since I needed to reset it.

I'm open to better options but here is how I solved it:

```js
console.clear();
let counter = 0;
const data = new Rx.BehaviorSubject(null);

function fetch() {
  data.next(counter++);
}

function manualGet() {
  console.log('manual');
  fetch();
}

// setup poll
data.switchMap(() => Rx.Observable.timer(5000))
  .subscribe(() => { 
    console.log('poll');
    fetch();
  });

// subscribe to the data
data.filter(x => x != null).
  subscribe(x => { console.log('data', x); });

// do the first fetch
fetch();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.5/Rx.min.js"></script>
<button onClick="manualGet()">Get Data</button>
```

With ngrx I am listening for the success action related to the fetch event.